# Print child nodes from ancestor

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

```
<Records> 
    <Record>
        <Field>Grandpa Field</Field>
        <Record>
            <Field>Son Field</Field>
                <Record>
            <Field>Child Field 1</Field>
            </Record>
            <Record>
                <Field>Child Field 2</Field>
            </Record>
        </Record>   
    </Record>
</Records>
```

Based on this XML structure and following a tutorial, I'm new to XSLT, I have created the following XLST transform file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="Records">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Grandpa Field</th>
            <th>Son Field</th>
            <th>Child Field</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:for-each select="Record">
                <xsl:value-of select="Field" />
              </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:for-each select="Record/Record">
                <xsl:value-of select="Field" />
              </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:for-each select="Record/Record/Record">
                <xsl:value-of select="Field" />
              </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
Grandpa Field |Son Field | Child Field 1Child Field 2
```

What I need to get as my final output is:

```
Grandpa Field |Son Field | Child Field 1
Grandpa Field |Son Field | Child Field 2
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Mind you, the HTML portion is not necessary but it was helpful to me when seeing the results.

Comment: Please post the result that you expect to get from your updated input.

Comment: Also, are you sure those are the correct IDs? It seems like the parentId of a record should link to some iD of its parent record, should it not?

Comment: I updated it and gave my expected result. At this point, it's becoming a bit confusing but I hope what I have makes sense.

Comment: @user1772421 - (1) You should accept one of the answers for your original question since both worked for you. (2) You should remove the edit with the new question. (3) You should ask a new question.

Comment: Created a new question as suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289292/xsl-transform-multiple-child-nodes-multiple-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the following approach.

1. Find all the leaf `<Record>` elements (those that don't contain any further Records). That's easy: `//Record[not(Record)]`.
2. For each of them, output all their ancestors separated by `|` and then a newline.

The following simple transformation does exactly that:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Record[not(Record)]" mode="line" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Record" mode="line">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::Record" />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Record">
        <xsl:value-of select="Field" />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>|</xsl:text></xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Applied to your sample input this generates:

```
Grandpa Field|Son Field|Child Field 1
Grandpa Field|Son Field|Child Field 2
```

See: http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQo

Comment: Hey, I have updated my post. Unfortunately, I did not figure out how to add your code to what I had already written. Could you please take a look at the edit? Greatly appreciate it!!!!

Comment: First observation: I **strongly** dis-recommend using "counted" element names like `<Relationship_2">`. If the thing defines a relationship, call it `<Relationship>`, if it needs a counter, give it an attribute. `<Relationship level="2">`. In other words, there is no *semantic* difference between `<Relationship_2>` and `<Relationship_3>`, so they should not have different names. You'll make your life unnecessarily complicated by appending those counters.

Comment: Second observation ([now sorted out](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28289292/18771)): You completely altered your question in mid-flight. The input is different, the requirements are different, the output is different. Don't do that. You are wasting everyone's time (including your own) when you try to make your problem "simpler" than it is and end up asking something you don't want to know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your XSLT is that it only creates one row in the table for each "Grandpa Field" when you want an entry for each "Child Field".

If all your XML looks like this example, then the simplest thing would be to iterate through each "Child field" with an `xsl:foreach` and create table rows at that level, like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="Records">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Grandpa Field</th>
            <th>Son Field</th>
            <th>Child Field</th>
          </tr>

          <xsl:for-each select="Record/Record/Record">

            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="../../Field"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="../Field"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Field"/>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </xsl:for-each>

        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, you will need a more sophisticated approach than this if your XML gets more complicated than in your example. For example, if every entry is not a Grandpa/Son/Child, but instead there are sometimes different numbers of levels in the hierarchy (e.g. sometimes just Son/Child, or maybe some of Grandpa's Sons don't have children) then this XSLT example will omit those entries.